# Is there a way to edit the dropdown list of an excel spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, formatting, office365, color-scheme, custom-cell

I'm using data validation to create a dropdown list from a specific range of cells and that works normally, but it would be really nice if I can add some color to the dropdown list itself.

This is different than the selected cell - I'm not looking for a conditional formatting option for the selected option - instead, I want to format the dropdown itself.

[image]

I know about conditional formatting for the cell, but this is not that.  I'm guessing this is related to the theme of office, but I'm not sure.  Just checking to see if anyone has ever run across this before.

Comment: no - that is not possible